# Why wont my ruby server load in terminal on os x 10.7

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, webrick

I am currently following an online video from Lynda.com, on Ruby on Rails essentials. I am a beginner in web development an am trying to practice using rails web app framework. So far I have updated all of my gems, installed mysql2, and am using the defaulted WEBrick server. However as I try to activate my server I get the following message.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:3: undefined method `source_index' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `gem_original_require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/setup.rb:1
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `gem_original_require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
from /Users/greghughes/Sites/simple_cms/config/boot.rb:6
from script/rails:5:in `require'
from script/rails:5
```

Im not quite sure what the error is as I'm also just familiarizing myself with UNIX. If anyone has any solutions or advice it would be much appreciated.

Comment: How did you install ruby?  Are you using RVM?  Are you sure you're using ruby 1.8?

Comment: I'm not sure what RVM is. As far as I understand Ruby came pre-installed on OS X 10.7. I had updated Ruby and its current version is 1.8.7 and is located at /usr/bin/ruby

Comment: Did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: Yes, and I still get the same message. Does it matter what directory I run bundle install in? My project "simple_cms" lies in the "Sites" directory given to you in OS X, and I am executing the command inside there.

Comment: I'd ditch the video and follow https://rvm.io/ and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: I suppose I will, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using
gem update --system.

Comment: When I try this command the following prompt appears: Latest version currently installed. Aborting.